# Is there a linq-y way to union collection properties of a collection of objects?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Sorry, that title just hurts.  I'm wondering if there is a Linq to collections extension method that collapses the following code segment into a single line:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetAllChildren(IEnumerable<Parent> parents){

  var result = new List<Child>();

  foreach(Parent parent in parents)
    foreach(Child child in parent.Children)
      result.Add(child);

  return result;
}
```

If you can collapse that into a single statement, try it on insane difficulty:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetAllChildren(IEnumerable<Grandparent> nanas){

  var result = new List<Child>();

  foreach(Grandparent papa in nanas)
    foreach(Parent parent in papa.Children)
      foreach(Child child in parent.Children)
        result.Add(child);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the obligatory method form.

```
return parents
  .SelectMany(p => p.Children);
```

And for two levels:

```
return oldies
  .SelectMany(grand => grand.Children)
  .SelectMany(parent => parent.Children);
```

Answer (score 9):

This will work:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetAllChildren(IEnumerable<Parent> parents)
{
    return from parent in parents
           from child in parent.Children
           select child;
}
```

and then this:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetAllChildren(IEnumerable<Grandparent> nanas)
{
    return from papa in nanas
           from parent in papa.Children
           from child in parent.Children
           select child;
}
```

Note, in this example I'm not actually returning a list, I'm returning an IEnumerable data source that until you start to foreach over it, or similar, won't actually do any processing.

If you need to return a list, modify each return statement as follows:

```
    return (from .....
            ...
            select child).ToList();
```

Comment: The return value has to be an IEnumerable, and the easiest way (at least as far as I know) to do that is return a collection that implements IEnumerable.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can return a collection, or use yield return, look up the yield keyword on msdn if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Good point on the yield...  I usually don't do that in these types of cases due to a step along the way failing, in which case I just return the empty collection.  Its pretty obvious what I'm doing, whereas a yield sometimes isn't clear what happens in these cases for people who come behind me...